# How to add a welcome message in slackbot built On Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, slack-block-kit

Is it possible (without coding) to pop up a welcome message when the Slackbot (built on WA) is invited to a channel or is first-time added? How?

I tried to follow the guide Starting and ending the dialog(https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-start) to set up the dialogue, but failed - when I invited it to a slack channel, no welcome msg is displayed. I guess I might missed some steps. Could anyone help to provide some guidance? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible because of a Slack limitation. See this snippet from the [docs page on dialog start](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-start) which you linked to:

> However, the Welcome node is skipped in situations when the user initiates the conversation by sending a message, such as with the Slack and Facebook integrations.

BTW: You linked to the "classic experience", the now outdated Assistant version. There is [documentation on the current Watson Assistant and the Slack integration](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-deploy-slack). A similar limitation is documented:

> The welcome action is not processed by the Slack integration. The welcome message is not displayed in the Slack channel like it is in the assistant preview. It is not triggered from here because nodes with the welcome special condition are skipped in action flows that are started by users. Slack waits for the user to initiate the conversation.